# setContentView(R.layout.main); main is showing error

Tags: android

Here is coding

```
package todo.list;

import android.R;
import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TodolistActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btnSave = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText txtEdit=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String message = txtEdit.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(TodolistActivity.this, message, 20).show();
             }
        });

    }

}
```

I import all classes but still its showing an error with connection to my main.xml

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

main is showing error

> MAIN CAN NOT BE RESOLVED OR IS NOT A FIELD

Answer (score 2):

Delete these lines:

```
import android.R;
import android.R.layout;
```

If using Eclipse, hit Command(Cntrl)+Shift+O after, or replace with

`import todo.list.R`

Answer (score 2):

clean your project then re build it again

projects -- > clean

projects --> build all

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import android.R;
import android.R.layout;
```

to

```
import todo.list.R
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I resolve the error by replacing,

`setContentView(R.layout.main);` with

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);`

which was the name of the activity I specified while starting the project.

Answer (score -2):

In my case,I resolve the error by moving the java file to /src/*my_project*
where my_project is the name package where the main activity is taking place